# Moment of inertia of a hollow sphere wrt the centre?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, moment-of-inertia

I've been trying to compute the moment of inertia of a uniform hollow sphere (thin walled) wrt the centre, but I'm not quite sure what was wrong with my initial attempt (I've come to the correct answer now with a different method). Ok, here was my first method:

Consider a uniform hollow sphere of radius $R$ and mass $M$. On the hollow sphere, consider a concentric ring of radius $r$ and thickness $\text{d}x$. The mass of the ring is therefore $\text{d}m = \frac{M}{4\pi R^2}\cdot 2\pi r\cdot\text{d}x$. Now, use $r^2 = R^2 - x^2:$
$$\text{d}m = \frac{M}{4\pi R^2}\cdot 2\pi \left(R^2 - x^2 \right)^{1/2}\text{d}x$$
and the moment of inertia of a ring wrt the centre is $I = MR^2$, therefore:
$$\text{d}I = \text{d}m\cdot r^2 = \frac{M}{4\pi R^2}\cdot 2\pi\left(R^2 - x^2\right)^{3/2}\text{d}x $$
Integrating to get the total moment of inertia:
$$I = \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{M}{4\pi R^2} \cdot 2\pi\cdot \left(R^2 - x^2\right)^{3/2}\ \text{d}x = \frac{3MR^2 \pi}{16}$$

which obviously isn't correct as the real moment of inertia wrt the centre is $\frac{2MR^2}{3}$.

What was wrong with this method? Was it how I constructed the element? Any help would be appreciated, thanks very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The mass of the ring is wrong. The ring ends up at an angle, so its total width is not $dx$ but $\frac{dx}{sin\theta}$

You made what I believe was a typo when you wrote

$$\text{d}m = \frac{M}{4\pi R^2}\cdot 2\pi \left(R^2 - x^2 \right)\text{d}x$$

because based on what you wrote further down, you intended to write

$$\text{d}m = \frac{M}{4\pi R^2}\cdot 2\pi \sqrt{\left(R^2 - x^2 \right)}\text{d}x$$

This problem is much better done in polar coordinates - instead of $x$, use $\theta$. But the above is the basic reason why you went wrong.

In essence, $sin\theta=\frac{r}{R}$ so you could write

$$\text{d}m = \frac{M}{4\pi R^2}\cdot 2\pi \frac{r}{sin\theta} \ \text{d}x \\
= \frac{M}{4\pi R^2}\cdot 2\pi \frac{r}{\frac{r}{R}} \ \text{d}x\\
= \frac{M}{4\pi R^2}\cdot 2\pi R \ \text{d}x\\
= \frac{M}{2 R} \ \text{d}x$$

Now we can substitute this into the integral:

$$I = \int_{-R}^{R} \frac{M}{2 R} \cdot \left(R^2 - x^2\right)\ \text{d}x \\
= \frac{M}{2R}\left[{2R^3-\frac23 R^3}\right]\\
= \frac23 M R^2$$

Comment: Thanks for answering, and I've arrived at the correct answer using the polar coordinates method, I was wondering what was wrong with this method. Your answer makes sense, but I'm not quite sure now why a similar technique (as in the OP) works for a solid sphere and a plate of thickness $\text{d}x$ but a similar doesn't work for a hollow sphere with a ring. Could I ask you to clarify this, please? Thank you.

Comment: The difference is that when you have a solid object, the angle at the edge is insignificant; but when you have a thin shell, that angle becomes hugely significant. I have expanded my answer to show how to finish the derivation using the method you started (without resorting to polar coordinates). It turns out that things cancel quite nicely...

Comment: @Floris, In3rd step you have written, that area of the strip is independent of the distance from the axis. i.e you have written it to be $2\pi R dx$, how can that be right?

Comment: @fahd as the radius gets smaller, the angle of the strip also becomes more perpendicular to the axis of revolution. The two factors exactly cancel each other out, so the area is constant. That’s just how the math works...

Comment: Is there a reason why angle at edge is insignificant for solid object but significant for hollow object? Also if width of disc is taken to be $Rd\theta$, will it produce a more accurate expression for solid sphere?