# Moment of inertia of hollow sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, moment-of-inertia

I know the moment of inertia of a filled sphere is $(2/5) Mr^2$. How do you show the moment of inertia of a hollow sphere is $(2/3) Mr^2$?

Comment: To find the inertia of a spheres you would use integration for a plane circular disc and integrate it. For a hollow sphere use a circle and integrate it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Moment of inertia of a hollow sphere wrt the centre?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109761/)

Answer (score 0):

First, be careful about symbols: $M$ in the two cases depends on $r$ in different ways. For the sphere it’s $(4/3 \pi r^3) \rho$, but for a shell of thickness $\Delta r$ it’s $(4 \pi r^2 \Delta r) \rho$.

Consider how $I$ changes with $r$. Adding a bit to $r$ adds a thin *shell* to the sphere, and the increase in $I$ is the moment of that shell.

$I_{\rm{shell}} = \Delta I = \rm{d/dr} ((4/3 \pi r^3 \rho)  (2/5r^2)) \Delta r$

$= (4 \pi r^2 \rho \Delta r) 2/3 r^2 =  2/3 M r^2$

To do it without calculus, again start with the idea that the moment of the thin shell is the difference of the moment of sphere-with-shell, i.e. a sphere of radius $r+\Delta r$, and the moment of the original sphere of radius $r$:

$I_{\rm{shell}} = \Delta I = (4/3 \pi (r+\Delta r)^3 \rho)  (2/5(r+\Delta r)^2)) - (4/3 \pi r^3 \rho)  (2/5r^2))$

First you simplify that with algebra:

$ = 8/15 \pi \rho ( (r+\Delta r)^5 - (r)^5)$

Then you use a binomial expansion based on the idea that $\Delta r$ is very small compared to $r$ (the shell is not thick compared to its radius):

$ = 8/15 \pi \rho ( (r^5+ 5 r^4 \Delta r + 20 r^3 \Delta r^2 + ...) - r^5)$

$ = 8/15 \pi \rho (5 r^4 \Delta r) = (4/3 \pi r^2 \Delta r \rho) 2/5 r^2$

$ = 2/5 M r^2$

To put it another way, you get a factor of 5 because the moment depends on volume (3 powers of $r$) and on distance from center squared (2 powers of $r). But you lose a factor of 3 because of 4/3 in the volume of a sphere vs 4 in the surface.

Comment: Please add this calculation.

Comment: I added it in the middle.